# Regular expression is not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am doing amount validation.  The requirements are:

1. There should not be a leading zero.
2. It should accept only numbers.
3. There should be a single decimal point.
4. it should accept 9 digits before decimal and 2 digits after decimal.

I have tried this regex:

```
/^(([1-9]\d{0,8})(\.\d{1,2})?)/g;
```

The issue is, after entering 9 digits, decimal is getting entered only if you enter any digits along with it simultaneously (at a time), without it I am unable enter decimal point.

Comment: You want to be able to enter a decimal without a number following it?

Comment: So you want to allow `123.` as valid input

Comment: A `\d{0,2}` should allow that.

Comment: yes absolutely .. not simultaneously.First i should be able to enter decimal point,then the numbers

Comment: @Aishwarya then what kenney said should work for you...

Comment: @brso05 yeah Kenny code is working well

Comment: @Kenney  thanks a lot, its working fine

Comment: Np. Btw, you might want to add a `$` to the end of the regexp, otherwise `123.1foobar` is also matched.

Comment: Without $, its working fine.And with $,its erasing everything if we enter the 10th digit

Answer (score 1):

This could help:

```
/^(?!0)\d{1,9}\.\d{0,2}$/
```

In this case, I used a lookahed (`(!?0)`) to prevent a leading zero, then used a similar OP expression to match the string. It means that everything in expression `\d{1,9}\.\d{0,2}` and not preceded by a zero will be matched.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tQ3uJ2/2)